# exit() gets skipped/ignored and not stops the script execution

Tags: php

I'm using Zend Framework 3 and my server and php versions are as follows:

> PHP 7.2.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)

When my script is run and hits the [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) command, it should stop the execution of the script but instead it continues to next statement.

e.g.

```
<?php
die;
echo 123;
```

?>

This script will print 123.

If I'm correct it shouldn't happen. what can be the cause for it?

Comment: You definitely don't output `123` anywhere else? Is this via the CLI, or browser? Are you doing any multi-thread magic? I don't know of any way that exit / die wouldn't stop the current script.

Comment: no, I'm running it on my browser and the cli, same result... no multi-thread magic...

Comment: See this [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ff7a1637535baaf6b26b68017b2d73d56c1afa9) works as expected, maybe it's just your copy of PHP  J/P  :-p

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the pecl packages, It was found that [uopz](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uopz.php) package (version: 5.1) breaks the correct behavior for exit command.

possible solution is to add:

```
<?php

uopz_allow_exit(true);

exit;

echo "Foo Bar Bar";//will not print anything
```